# String Alignment

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, string-formatting

I am trying to put the resultset of an unknown SQL query in a javafx TextArea in a  form of table. I managed to do it perfectly but i had small problems with alignment. 
[Here is the result that i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWW2Z.jpg)

Here is my my code:

```
        private void querySubmitButtonClicked() {
        try {
        String q = queryTF.getText();
        PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(q);
        if ((q.startsWith("INSERT")) || (q.startsWith("UPDATE")) || (q.startsWith("DELETE")))
            ps.executeUpdate();
        else
            queryResult = ps.executeQuery();

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = queryResult.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String columnsNames = "";

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
            columnsNames += String.format("%-40s", rsmd.getColumnName(i));

        sb.append(columnsNames + "\n");
        while (queryResult.next()) {
            String columnsValues = "";
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                columnsValues += String.format("%-40s", queryResult.getString(i));
            }
            sb.append(columnsValues + "\n");
        }
        TextArea resultArea = new TextArea(sb.toString());
        resultArea.setEditable(false);
        resultArea.setFocusTraversable(false);
        resultArea.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 10");
        expertPane.setCenter(resultArea);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        expertPane.setCenter(msgLabel);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried using right allignemnt by using %40s, but it wouldnt allign correctly also. I also tried using %100s and %-100s it didnt work also.
Any help ?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to use a monospaced font? Like Monaco or Courier New.

Comment: @OleV.V. changing the font to Courier New solved my problem !! Thank youu a lott !

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in a comment, use a monospaced (fixed-width) font, like Monaco or Courier New. This should do it.

I don’t know FX, but I think another option would be to use a `TableView` instead of the `TextArea`.

Comment: I used table view a lot in my project. But doing this in a tableview is very complicated/impossible since i dont know the type, number, and size of my data; it depends on the user's query.
Anyway thank you, changing the font solved my problem !

Comment: Yeah, I too was thinking `TableView` might be the complicated option. Just wanted to mention for the sake of completeness — maybe it wasn’t relevant at all.